# Why do I get syntax error for reassignment in verilog code?

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

```
module test;
    reg[8:0] a;

    initial begin
        a= 4'b0001;
        a= 4'b0002;
    end
endmodule
```

I am a beginner to `Verilog`. Why do I get syntax error for second `a` assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the re-assignment.

You are using base 2: `4'b` and then the digit 2. Try `4'b0010` :-)

Post edit: Why are you assigning 4 bits when the variable is 9 bits long?